# daily wp_schedule_event hook works after reload any page

Tags: wp-cron

I've put this code to my wordpress `functions.php` file. But this code works after any page reload on my site and sends sms.
what is the problem?
How can I understand daily scheduled event is set or not?

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled('daily_send_sms_hook')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'daily_send_sms_hook');
}
add_action('daily_send_sms_hook', 'daily_send_sms');

function daily_send_sms() {
    // send sms code
}
```